# Fixing Tic-Tac-Toe Code Error.. Doesn't Run Due to DeclareWinner function bein written later. How can I correct it?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

The entire code for my Tic Tac Toe game has been pasted below. It doesn't run due to an error in the Declare Winner function being added after its use. How do I correct this?
Do I simply create it earlier?

Use of local variable 'DeclareWinner' before its declaration. This is what it says. What am I supposed to do?

```
  import UIKit

  class GameViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var MainTitle: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var Player1Label: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var Player2Label: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var PlayerTurnLabel: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var GameONLabel: UILabel!

var matrix: [[Int]] = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]  // 0 - Nothing, 1 - X, 2 - O

var WhosTurn = 0 // 1- Player1, 2- Player2

var Player1 = 0 // 0 - Nothing, 1 - X, 2 - O
var Player2 = 0 // 0 - Nothing, 1 - X, 2 - O

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    StartGame()
    
}

func StartGame(){
    
    matrix = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]   // 0 - Nothing, 1 - X, 2 - O
    displayMat(matrix: matrix)
    
    WhosTurn = Int.random(in: 1...2)
    
    if (WhosTurn == 1){ // Player1's Turn and He's X
        
        Player1 = 1
        Player2 = 2
        
        Player1Label.text = "Player 1: X"
        Player2Label.text = "Player 2: O"
        
        PlayerTurnLabel.text = "Turn: Player 1"
        
        
    }else {// Player2's Turn and He'll be O
        
        Player1 = 2
        Player2 = 1
        Player1Label.text = "Player 1: O"
        Player2Label.text = "Player 2: X"
        
        PlayerTurnLabel.text = "Turn: Player 2"
    }
    
}

func displayMat(matrix: [[Int]]) {
    
    
    var TempTag = 1
    for i in 0...2  {
        for j in 0...2  {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 0 )  {
                let TempButton = self.view.viewWithTag(TempTag) as? UIButton
                TempButton?.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .normal)
                
            }  else if (matrix[i][j] == 1) { //Display X
                let TempButton = self.view.viewWithTag(TempTag) as? UIButton
                TempButton?.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "X"), for: .normal)

            }else if (matrix[i][j] == 2)  { //Display O
                let TempButton = self.view.viewWithTag(TempTag) as? UIButton
                TempButton?.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "O"), for: .normal)

            }else {
                
            }
            
            TempTag += 1
        }
    }
    
}


@IBAction func ButtonClickedXorO(_ sender: Any) {
    
    var TempObject = 0
    
    if (WhosTurn == 1){ // Player1's Turn and He's X
        TempObject = Player1
        Player1 = 1
        Player2 = 2
        
        Player1Label.text = "Player 1: X"
        Player2Label.text = "Player 2: O"
        
        PlayerTurnLabel.text = "Turn: Player 1"
        
        
    }else {// Player2's Turn and He'll be O
        TempObject = Player2
        PlayerTurnLabel.text = "Turn: Player 2"
    }
    
    guard let button = sender as? UIButton else {
        return
    }
    
    switch button.tag {
    case 1:
        if (matrix[0][0] == 0) {
            matrix[0][0] = TempObject
            JustPlayed()
        }
    case 2:
    if (matrix[0][1] == 0) {
        matrix[0][1] = TempObject
        JustPlayed()
    }
    case 3:
    if (matrix[0][2] == 0) {
        matrix[0][2] = TempObject
        JustPlayed()
    }
    case 4:
    if (matrix[1][0] == 0) {
        matrix[1][0] = TempObject
        JustPlayed()
    }
    case 5:
    if (matrix[1][1] == 0) {
        matrix[1][1] = TempObject
        JustPlayed()
    }
    case 6:
    if (matrix[1][2] == 0) {
        matrix[1][2] = TempObject
        JustPlayed()
    }
    case 7:
    if (matrix[2][0] == 0) {
        matrix[2][0] = TempObject
        JustPlayed()
    }
    case 8:
    if (matrix[2][1] == 0) {
        matrix[2][1] = TempObject
        JustPlayed()
    }
    case 9:
    if (matrix[2][2] == 0) {
        matrix[2][2] = TempObject
        JustPlayed()
    }
        
    default:
        print("Error")
    }
}

func JustPlayed(){
    
    displayMat(matrix: matrix)
    Winner()
    
    if (WhosTurn == 1) {
        
        WhosTurn = 2
        PlayerTurnLabel.text = "Turn: Player 2"
        
    }else {
        WhosTurn = 1
        PlayerTurnLabel.text = "Turn: Player 1"
    }

}

func Winner(){
    
    var Counter = true
    
    if ((matrix[0][0] == matrix[1][1] && matrix[1][1] == matrix[2][2] && matrix[1][1] != 0))
      DeclareWinner(WhoWon: matrix[1][1])
        
    }else if ((matrix[2][0] == matrix[1][1] && matrix[1][1] == matrix[0][2] && matrix[1][1] != 0)) {
        DeclareWinner(WhoWon: matrix[1][1])
        
    }else {
        
        for i in 0...2{
            if (matrix[i][0] == matrix[i][1] && matrix[i][1] == matrix[i][2] && matrix[i][0] != 0){
                DeclareWinner(WhoWon: matrix[i][0])
                Counter = false
            }
        }
        
        if Counter{
            for i in 0...2{
                if (matrix[0][i] == matrix[1][i] && matrix[1][i] == matrix[2][i] && matrix[0][i] != 0){
                    DeclareWinner(WhoWon: matrix[0][i])
                }
            }
        
    }
    
}

func DeclareWinner(WhoWon: Int){
    if (WhoWon == Player1) {
        // Player1 Won
        GameONLabel.text = "Player 1 Won!"
        
    }else if (WhoWon == Player2){
        //Player2 Won
        GameONLabel.text = "Player 2 Won!"
        
    }
    
}
/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@IBAction func GoBack(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

}

Comment: In your function `Winner`, you are missing a `{` after the first `if`.  And then you need to add a `}` to the bottom of `Winner`.

Comment: Some comments about your formatting. Variable names and function names should start with lowercase letters.  Uppercase is used for `class`, `struct`, and `protocol` names and types such as `Int` and `Double`.

Comment: Theres also an error in the GoBack function, Can you please help me out?

Comment: What is the error? It compiles.